# get attribute from selectNodes in JavaScript and XML?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I am trying to get an attribute from an XML node from JavaScript.

item.selectNodes("enclosure[@url]")

That is not working like I thought it would :(

Any hints ?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[@url]
```

is a predicate, which does not select the attribute but filters the "enclosure" nodes that do have a url attribute.

In XPath,

```
enclosure/@url
```

would select the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
item.selectNodes("enclosure[@url]")
```

will give you a collection of `enclosure` nodes that have a `url` attribute.

To get a collection of `url` attribute nodes that are on `enclosure` nodes, do this:

```
item.selectNodes("enclosure/@url")
```

Which you must then loop over to get the values of each one.  Remember this gives you attribute **nodes**, not attribute **values**.  You can use `attributeNode.nodeValue` to get the value from the node.

If you are expecting just one such node, then use [selectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `selectNodes`.  This will give you the first matching node, instead of a collection of all matching nodes.